# Installed Node and Chocolatey on windows Admin powershell, but its not in regular the powershell

Tags: node.js, windows, powershell, chocolatey

so I'm installing Node and Chocolatey in windows and was able to do it in the admin powershell, but not the regular powershell, where my project is. In the Admin powershell I have the v0.11.3 version of Chocolatey and the v17.2.0 of Node. When I test to see if Node and Chocolatey is installed in the regular powershell, I get a error saying the term is not recognized. I'm not understanding why this is happening, can someone shed some light.

Comment: Have you tried starting a new PowerShell session / logging off and on again / rebooting?

Answer (score 1):

If you installed them as an admin, then you are literally running that shell as the admin/root user. When you install software like node.js, it adds the executable path to the path environmental variable (`env:path` on windows, `$PATH` on linux/unix). But when you then try to use it as a different user, it won't have been added to the path environmental variable. To get it to work, you will likely need to add the node path to your path environmental variable list.